# Añadir un If en un fichero .ASPX

Tags: c#, aspx

Tengo esta parte de mi código:

```
<BaseParams>
        <ext:Parameter Name="start" Value="0" Mode="Raw" />
        <ext:Parameter Name="limit" Value="30" Mode="Raw" />
        <ext:Parameter Name="sort" Value="Referencia" Mode="Value" />
        <ext:Parameter Name="direction" Value="ASC" Mode="Value" />
        <ext:Parameter Name="gerencia" Value="CBO_FIL_GERENCIA.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
```

Y me gustaría que en vez de coger el de gerencia de CBO_FIL....

Antes haga un if. Como puedo introducir un if? mi idea sería hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
If (gerencia value = null ) 
x
Else
 <ext:Parameter Name="gerencia" Value="CBO_FIL_GERENCIA.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
```

Podéis ayudarme?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dentro del value podes usar las marcas para escribir codigo c#, por ejemplo:

```
<ext:Parameter Name="gerencia" Value="<% gerencia.value == null ? CBO_FIL_GERENCIA.getValue() : otracosa.getValue() %>" Mode="Raw" />
```

Comment: gracias!! me ha ido perfecto!